# Accessing config file from c# interactive window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-interactive

I'm trying to run some code in the VS2015 c# interactive window which uses a connection string stored in the app.config file of a dll which I'm referencing using the `#r` function.

If I look in the `ConfigurationManager` there is a connection string in it but it's a different one which it must be referencing from another config file.

Comment: `ConfigurationManager` accesses the app.config of executing assembly. Always add connection strings which your application accesses to app.config of executing assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to explicitly load the configuration for a specific assembly and explicitly access it, you can use the [OpenExeConfiguration method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437) of the [ConfigurationManager class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager).

Take a test.dll assembly with this test.dll.config configuration file:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add
       name="MyConnectionString"
       connectionString="my connection string"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
   />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

You cam load the configuration file like this:

```
> #r "c:\temp\test.dll"
> #r "System.Configuration"
> using System.Configuration;
> ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(@"c:\temp\test.dll").ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString
"my connection string"
```

Comment: That gets the configuration details but it doesn't merge it with the configuration settings the code I'm calling references. I either need to merge the configuration settings with the executing assemblies settings or I need to edit the config file Roslyn is using. Not sure where that is though...

Comment: "Roslyn" has nothing to do with. "Roslyn" is the compiler and configuration loading is a runtime feature.

Comment: That's why I said explicitly. You could try to inject the configuration from that file into the loaded condiguration `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("yoursection")`. But that won't work if that configuration is read-only. Or you could grab csi.exe and csi.exe.config and add your configuration to it.